# Is there a connection between the Hyuuga curse mark and Orochimaru's?

Tags: naruto

The Hyuuga family has a curse mark that allows the head family to destroy the brains of members of the branch family. Orochimaru has a curse mark that he puts on Sasuke, as well as other people, that makes the person whose body it is on be much stronger. Is there any connection between these two curse marks?

Answer (score 2):

As far as now, the only connection is that they are all juinjutsu. But their functions are totally different. The curse mark of Hyuuga family is literally a curse (I don't see how much stronger the branch family of Hyuuga is with the curse seal), but the curse seal of Orochimaru has some blessing, and it's created by infusing senjutsu into enzymes extracted from Jugo's body, which grants the seal-bearer the ability of transforming parts of their body (except the fact that they may look uglier), and the bearer's power is indeed stronger when the seal is released.